# Postnikov towers are unique up to homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

> I want to prove that a Postnikov tower is unique up to homotopy equivalence.

**Edit** Let us also assume all spaces to be $CW$-complexes.

A Postnikov tower is defined (on a base space $X$) as maps $X \rightarrow X_n$ and connecting maps $X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}$ for which the following hold:

1. The map $X \rightarrow X_n$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for all $i < n$
2. $\pi_i(X_n) = 0$ for all $i > n$

---

Suppose there exists two such towers $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ and $\overline{X_1}, \cdots , \overline{X_n}$.

There is a commutative diagram as follows:
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>f>> X_n\\ @.     {_{\rlap{h}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVgV\\  @. \overline{X_n} \end{CD}$$

Passing the $\pi_i$ functor we get isomorphisms for each of the arrows (in other words the map $\pi_i(g):\pi_i(X_n) \rightarrow \pi_i(\overline{X_n})$ is well defined and indeed an isomorphism)
This makes all the towers associated with a base space $X$ to be equivalent up to homotopy.

---

I believe that this proof is flawed. Is there any way I can use an analogous argument?

**Edit**:
Let us define the map $g$ such that it proves weak homotopy equivalence and then maybe I can use the Whitehead's theorem which says that for $CW$- complexes homotopy equivalence is the same as weak homotopy equivalence.

Let $f_*: \pi_i(X) \rightarrow \pi_i(X_n)$ and $h_*:\pi_i(X) \rightarrow \pi_i(\overline{X_n})$. Now if $\require{AMScd} \pi_i(X) \ni [\alpha] \mapsto [\beta] \in \pi_i(X_n)$ (under $f_*$) and $\require{AMScd} \pi_i(X) \ni [\alpha] \mapsto [\sigma] \in \pi_i(\overline{X_n})$ (under $h_*$) then $\require{AMScd} \pi_i(X_n) \ni [\beta] \mapsto [\sigma] \in \pi_i(\overline{X_n})$ (under $g_*$)

Thus making it weakly homotopy equivalent?

---

**Edit**: To see that $g_n$ indeed exists with the following properties we shall define it to be $h_n(f_n^{-1})$. Since the homotopy functor $\pi_i$ respects compositions (and $\pi_i(f)$ and $\pi_i(h)$ are both isomorphisms) we have that $\pi_i(g_n)$ is also an isomorphism.

> I don't know how to frame it in a better way but here is an example:
> $$G \overset{\cong} \longrightarrow \overline{G} \overset{\cong} \longrightarrow K$$ where both the morphisms are isomorphisms. Now since $\overline{G} \rightarrow K$ is an isomorphism so is its inverse $K \rightarrow \overline{G}$ and similarly for the pair $G$ and $\overline{G}$ we see that the composition $G \rightarrow K$ should also be an isomorphism.

However I believe I am assuming some things (like continuity of $f,h$ etc). Is there any way to wind things up?

---

Comment: Your condition 1. fails to mention a range of $i$ for which this holds. Your proof is flawed because you don't argue where the maps $g$ come from. Even then, the argument only shows that $g$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, not necessarily a homotopy equivalence. Usually, I think people make additional assumptions like that the maps in the Postnikov tower are fibrations and/or that the spaces involved are CW-complexes (but I don't think you can have both unless you also assume that the space $X$ is nice enough).

Comment: @Thorgott Say we have all of them to be $CW$-complexes would the argument then work? As for the $i$ there is no specific restriction (thus we will assume $i \in \mathbb{N}$)

Comment: There has to be a restriction. If $\pi_i(X)\rightarrow\pi_(X_n)$ is an isomorphism for all $i$ and $\pi_i(X_n)=0$ for $i>n$, then $\pi_i(X)=0$ for $i>n$, but there was no such assumption about $X$. Also, the argument still contains the massive gap that you need an argument for where the map $g$ comes from.

Comment: Your definition makes no assumption about the connecting maps, but they must at least be fibrations, no?

Comment: @Thorgott I did make a mistake while writing the definition the original definition is as follows: A Postnikov tower satisfies the two conditions (i) $X \rightarrow X_n$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ and (ii) $\pi_i(X_n) = 0$ for $i > n$

Comment: @Randall I have edited the post. I am still not sure about the definition of my map $g$ (whether it is well-defined and does what it should)

Comment: As Thorgott has already mentioned, not only is $g$ not well-defined, it has not even been defined.  I don't understand "Let's define the map $g$...." in the edit, because you have no guarantee there is such a map.  Compare it with "Let us define the map $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$ such that it proves a bijection."

Comment: I think you're also missing conditions in your definition of the Postnikov tower. The maps $X_n \to X_{n-1}$ should be fibrations and their fibers should be the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $K\left( \pi_n(X), n \right)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Could you please help me phrase it better or should I completely abandon that direction?

Comment: @JackDavidson I don't know. I copied the definition from a past problem set handed down to me (may be a printing mistake)

Comment: You either need to describe the maps $g_n:X_n\rightarrow \overline{X}_n$ or quote some theorem which gives the existence of some map having the properties you want.

Comment: @JasonDeVito can I define $g_n$ to be $h_n(f_n^{-1})$ and use the fact that $\pi_i$ respects compositions?

Comment: Does $f_n$ have an inverse?  (By the way, I wanted to mentioned that I attempted this problem from several directions and got stuck each time.  If I can actually figure out an answer, then I'll write one.  That said, Hatcher has a proof of this that I'm purposely avoiding for now.)